# Grassmannian, Plucker coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

In which books can I find something about the grassmannian and the plucker coordinates ?

Comment: maybe it helps [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two references that have an introduction to the Grassmannian and include a discussion of the Plucker embedding of the Grassmannian are Fulton's *Young Tableaux* and Griffith and Harris' *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*.

Answer (score 2):

Another nice book that describes Grassmanians very carefully and in a very clear way is the book by Milnor and Stasheff "Characteristic classes". You should take a look on Chapters 5 and 6.